# Understanding arp request tcpdump

Tags: networking, arp

I noticed the below tcp dump when pinging a docker container B on bridge B from a docker container A on bridge A.

Container A: 10.0.0.3   /    02:42:0a:00:00:03

Container B: 10.0.0.4   /    02:42:0a:00:00:04

What I don't understand in the below dump is why is there a arp request "who-has" with both src and destination mac address? And I don't see the arp-reply anywhere. From where is it getting the destination mac address? Container B is not even on the same bridge as container A.

Here is the tcpdump on eth0 of src container eth0.

```
root@nginx-rc-8sqxl:/# tcpdump -nei eth0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
00:34:02.048458 02:42:0a:00:00:03 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.3, length 28
00:34:02.048799 02:42:0a:00:00:03 > 02:42:0a:00:00:04, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.3, length 28
00:34:03.044847 02:42:0a:00:00:03 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.3, length 28
00:34:03.044880 02:42:0a:00:00:03 > 02:42:0a:00:00:04, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.3, length 28
00:34:04.044852 02:42:0a:00:00:03 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.3, length 28
00:34:04.044886 02:42:0a:00:00:03 > 02:42:0a:00:00:04, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.3, length 28
```

Comment: This looks like ARP cache validation. Which is a process whereby a host will attempt to validate an ARP record by sending a unicast ARP request to a knwon MAC address, and then deleting the entry from its ARP table if no reply is received. The only problem is that cache validation usually occurs minutes apart, whereas your packet trace shows these requests occurring one second apart, and at the same time as a regular ARP broadcast request. Do the two containers actually have L2 network connectivity between them? (I am not familiar with docker, or how containers are interconnected).